# c++ code time complexity of && operator

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I have the following 2 codes:

```
int i=0;
while(i<=1000000000 && i!=-1) {
    i++;        
}
```

I think the run-time complexity is 4 billion

In the while condition is 3 operations `(i<=1000000000),(i!=-1) and &&` ,
and

```
int i=0;
    while(i!=-1) {
        if(i>=1000000000) break;
        i++;        
    }
```

Which I think the run-time complexity is 3 billion, 
in the while condition is 1 operation `(i<=1000000000)` in the if is  1 operation `(i!=-1)`, 
But when I run it the two code have the same running time so why was that?

I have change the two codes a little bit as follow:

```
int n = 1000000000;
int i=0;
while(i<=n && i!=-1) {
    i++;        
}

int n = 1000000000;
int i=0;
while(i!=-1) {
if(i>=n) break;
    i++;        
}
```

This time the 3rd code block run in `2.6s` and the 4th is `3.1s`, 
Why was this happened? 
What was the time complexity of the four codes?

I use dev-c++ IDE.

Comment: Ditch the IDE, open a terminal and compile manually. Then, explore the joys of the `-S` command line switch (emit assembly) and compare the differences *in a release-optimized build*.

Comment: The code for all examples complexity is O(n) = C * n, where _n_ is number of iterations (1 bil. in your case) and _C_ is time spent per iteration (depends on code generated).

Comment: You might actually want to read up on what complexity is.  It is not measured as a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity and actual running time are two very different things.

Time complexity only has meaning when we are talking about variable input size. It tells how well algorithm scales for larger inputs. If we assume that your input is `n` (or `1000000000` in the first two cases), then all your examples have *linear* time complexity. It means, roughly, if you take `n` two times larger, running time is also doubled.

Actual running time somehow depends on complexity, but you can't reliably calculate it. Reasons are: compiler optimizations, CPU optimizations, OS thread management and many others.

I think by 'time complexity' you mean number of primitive operations for computer to execute. Then there are no difference between

```
while(i<=1000000000 && i!=-1)
```

and

```
while(i!=-1) {
    if(i>=1000000000) break;
```

because *most likely* operator `&&` implemented not as 'take first operand, take second operand, and perform some operation on them', but as a sequence of conditional jumps:

```
    if not FirstCondition then goto FalseBranch
    if not SecondCondition then goto FalseBranch
TrueBranch:
    ... here is your loop body
FalseBranch:
    ... here is the code after loop
```

And that's exactly what you did by hands in the second example.
However, this stuff is *only* makes sense to the specific compiler and optimization settings (in release build your loop will be eliminated entirely by any descent compiler).

Comment: @user1708860 it doesn't involve any side effects, so can be constant-folded to `i = 1000000001`